# Firebase-demo/Analytics NoClassDefFoundError exception when built with Gradle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I am having a NoClassDefFoundError exception when I added Firebase analytics on my game that is built with gradle so I tried it on this demo app of firebase(https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity) and got the same error but with different class. All I did was just change the build settings to gradle, I didnt change any gradle configuration.

My version of unity is 5.6.3f1.
I am using firebase_unity_sdk_5.2.1 plugin.

This is the error from the Analytics Quickstart demo:

09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject, PID: 2968
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement;
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnectorImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source:23)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.zzb.create(Unknown Source:8)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.components.zzh.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:29)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.components.zzi.get(Unknown Source:4)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.components.zzh.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:40)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer$$CC.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:15)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.components.zzd.get(Unknown Source:0)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.components.zzd.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:68)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:716)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:329)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:295)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:282)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:37)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1925)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1900)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:31)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6578)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6133)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6043)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject-KmqojsTcbAmAFIe0mAe1NA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject-KmqojsTcbAmAFIe0mAe1NA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject-KmqojsTcbAmAFIe0mAe1NA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
09-02 16:21:42.621  2968  2968 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 27 more

This is from my game:

09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject, PID: 29752
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions;
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:1050)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6578)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6133)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6043)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject-5mnEepmltZFu956Rz8DGDQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject-5mnEepmltZFu956Rz8DGDQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.DefaultProject-5mnEepmltZFu956Rz8DGDQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
09-02 15:12:24.259 29752 29752 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 12 more

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try removing `FirebaseCore` library from your project.